# Random directions

Tags: java, random

Hello I am busy with learning Java and I am busy creating a pacman game but now I need to let the ghosts move in a "Random" direction and so now and then this direction has to change vertically/horizontally and vica versa

at the moment the ghost goes from left to right and right to left. the code that is responsible for this action is as follows: (ignore pacman drawing part see below //ghost movement)

```
    DrawPacMan pacman = new DrawPacMan();
DrawGhost ghost = new DrawGhost();

int g1x = 0;
boolean g1r = true;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    // pacman movement
    diameter = 25;   
    pacman.drawPacMan(g, getHorPlaats(), getVerPlaats(), diameter, getView(), Color.yellow);

    // ghosts movement
    g1x += ghostSpeed * (g1r? 1 : -1);

    // check direction
    if (g1x >= 500) { g1x = 500; g1r = false; }
    else if (g1x <= 0) { g1x = 0; g1r = true; }

    ghost.drawGhost(g, g1x, 40, diameter, Color.red);

}
```

Now I don't know how to create a random direction or what functions to use. Can someone give me some hints/help and if possible a little example that I can work further with? and if you want to see more code or something please ask and i'll post :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
g1x += ghostSpeed * (Math.random() > 0.5? 1 : -1);
```

or even simpler:

```
g1x += ghostSpeed * Math.signum(Math.random() - 0.5);
```

This exploits the fact that [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) returns uniformly distributed value in `[0, 1)`.

But you'll quickly realize that such an algorithm will cause ghosts to move erratically, from left to right. You'll need something more elegant. E.g. if ghost moves to left, let him continue with 75% probability or change the direction with 25% of probability. I'll let you tackle this.

Comment: thanks! so in theory i can also use this to change it horizontally/vertically?

Comment: @Reshad:: well, even practically :-). However in practice, since ghost movements are limited by walls, you might first have to discover in which directions you *can* move and then randomize between them.

Comment: yeah well the game is not that difficult yet since I started with Java this is only for some exercise to get known to Java :)

Answer (score 2):

For something simple like this, I'd generate a random number, either 0, 1, 2, or 3. This will give you all the directions you need: up, down, left, and right.

```
 import java.util.Random;
 // create a random number generator
 Random randomGen = new Random();
 // generate a random number, between 0 and n-1 (0,1,2,3 in this case)
 int theRandomNumber = randomGen.nextInt(4);

 public void setRandomGhostDirection() {

     switch(theRandomNumber) {
     case 0:
         moveUp();
         break;
     case 1:
         moveLeft();
         break;
     case 2:
         moveRight();
         break;
     case 3:
         moveDown();
         break;
     }

 }
```

You could clean this up by defining the direction numbers as something like 
`final int DIRECTION_UP = 0` etc.

Comment: this is very clean example! ty very much!

Comment: Sure! Just make sure in your logic you only move in that direction if there's no barrier or anything in the way.

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() is the function that you're looking for. By itself, this function generates a random double from 0 to 1.

Pseudocode:

```
double randomDirection = Math.random();

if (direction > 0.25) {
 // move left if possible
} else if (direction > 0.5) {
 // move right if possible
} else if (direction > 0.75) {
 // move down if possible
} else {
 // move up if possible
}
```

Comment: ah thanks! thats what I need indeed I think i'll try to write this in working code :)